# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PhpMyAdmin\UserPreferences::apply()

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm make a new DB in localhost, and then I connect to my NetBeans project, I'ts succeeded, but the problem is when I open the localhost/phpMyAdmin I find this problem. Anyone can fixed?

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PhpMyAdmin\UserPreferences::apply() must be of the type array, null given, called in D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Config.php on line 929 and defined in D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\UserPreferences.php:177 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Config.php(929): PhpMyAdmin\UserPreferences->apply(NULL) #1 D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php(455): PhpMyAdmin\Config->loadUserPreferences() #2 D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\navigation.php(16): require_once('D:\xampp\phpMyA...') #3 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\UserPreferences.php on line 177

Comment: This looks like a PhpMyAdmin bug, not a programming problem by you.

Comment: It could be something misconfigured. Have you modified any of the files in the directory `D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin`?

Comment: i can't find where the error is. the last option is uninstalling xampp, and its work. thanks for all the omments,    ,    ,

Comment: For me it helped to clear the cache and the cookies of the phpMyAdmin URL in my browser.
The function throwing the error is loading some session related stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same kind of issue, clearing browser cache resolve the problem.